# alembic to autogenerated computed columns , generated as always in postgres

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic, sqlmodel

I have a column as such in my model:

```
class Mem(BaseMem,table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(sa_column=Column(Integer,Identity(always=True,start=1,cycle=True),primary_key=True,nullable=False))
    it_service_instance: Optional[str] = Column(String(),Computed("CASE WHEN environment = 'PROD' THEN it_service ELSE it_service || '-' || environment END",persisted=True),index=True)
    hostname: Optional[str] = Field(default=None,index=True)
    patch_version: Optional[str] = Field(default=None,index=True)
    product_alias: Optional[str] = Field(default=None,index=True)
```

When I try to autogenerate a migration with alembic i get the following:

```
op.add_column('mem', sa.Column('it_service_instance', sqlmodel.sql.sqltypes.AutoString(), nullable=True))
```

Can alembic autogenerated computed columns ?

I am getting this warning:

```
Computed default on mem.it_service_instance cannot be modified
  util.warn("Computed default on %s.%s cannot be modified" % (tname, cname))
```

Comment: It works ok with vanilla SQLAlchemy, if I try with SQLModel I get errors about validators so it needs a [mre].

Comment: Does your last edit mean that you are trying to change and existing generated column?  I don't think Postgres allows this for non-identity columns - you would need to drop and recreate it.